# Customize User Experience in Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I want to built a custom page where we ask the user for their email and then redirect them to the particular IDP page (we have logic built around this) using domain_hint, for example: domain_hint=facebook.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these samples:

Demonstrates how to implement a sign in journey, where the user is automatically directed to their federated identity provider based off of their email domain. And for users who arrive with an unknown domain, they are redirected to a default identity provider.
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery

Demonstrates how to create a home realm discovery page. On the sign-in page, the user provides their sign-in email address and clicks continue. B2C checks the domain portion of the sign-in email address. If the domain name is contoso.com the user is redirected to Contoso.com Azure AD to complete the sign-in. Otherwise the user continues the sign-in with username and password. In both cases (AAD B2C local account and AAD account), the user does not need to retype the user name.
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern

Comment: I created an HRD policy and now I have an orchestration step to first ask the user to enter their signIn name from which I am picking up the domain prefix which is used to redirect the user to appropriate IDP. But the scenario I want to implement is the user enters a login_hint of some kind in my application and I want to pass to the custom policy to filter the IDPs for the user. I don't want the B2C UI to pick the SignIn name instead I want to implement it at the application side. Is there a way I can enter the query parameter for the custom policy through the application.

Comment: Just swap the logic in this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/default-home-realm-discovery) from `domain_hint` to `login_hint`

Comment: I want to pass this login_hint from my application to custom policy, is that possible?